# Оптимизация - Rails belongs_to имеет проблему n+1, как сделать чтоб в sql был join?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Имею записи логов, у них есть отсылка на пользователя.

Модель логов

```
class Syslog < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
end
```

Модель пользователя ничего особенного не имеет, has_many я не добавлял там.

Теперь когда я делаю Syslog.all

А в представлении обращаюсь к пользователю:

```
    <% @syslogs.each do |syslog| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= syslog.datetime %></td>
        <td><%= syslog.user.username %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

В логах я вижу, что делается множество повторяющихся запросов.

```
  Syslog Load (1.2ms)  SELECT `SYSLOG`.* FROM `SYSLOG` INNER JOIN `USERS` ON `USERS`.`I_ID` = `SYSLOG`.`I_UID` WHERE (I_ELCAT <= '3') LIMIT 50
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:13
  User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 2 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 2 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 2 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 2 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 2 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 2 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 2 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 2 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 2 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 2 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 2 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 2 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 2 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = -20 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  User Load (2.2ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = -1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = -11 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = -1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = -11 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = -17 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = -1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = -11 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = -1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  User Load (2.1ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = -15 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = -20 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = -12 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = -13 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = -13 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = -13 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = -13 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = -13 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = -13 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = -18 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/syslogs/index.html.erb:16
  Rendered syslogs/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 163.4ms | Allocations: 64237)
  User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT `USERS`.* FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERS`.`I_ID` = 11 LIMIT 1
```

Получается технически сначала выбираются все логи.
А потом в цикле для каждого лога выбирается пользователь.

Мне надо сделать это одним или минимальным количеством запросов. Как этого добиться?

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Пункты 5 и 3. PS. И пофиг, как это делается в Руби - можете смело удалить.

Comment: Akina, Вы не правы. Вопрос в том, как сделать запрос SQL средствами Rails, чтобы избавиться от проблемы n+1.

Comment: *Вопрос в том, как сделать запрос SQL средствами Rails* Вы сами путаете других своей терминологией.  Запрос SQL - это запрос на языке SQL. А Вам нужен запрос, но не запрос SQL, а запрос в БД средствами RoR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не надо делать через join, в ActiveRecord есть разные варианты прелоада для этого

```
@syslogs = Syslog.includes(:user).all
```

Comment: Отлично! Это работает, такой способ мне подходит. 
Получается с помощью `include` он выбирает сначала `Syslog`, там определяет идентификаторы пользователей, а потом выбирает `users` с условием `where in`.

А если ли еще способ, чтобы в результате получился один запрос sql, например `select * from syslogs  inner join users on syslogs.user_id = users.id`?

Или такое нельзя сделать по каким-то причинам?
Почему через join лучше не делать?

Comment: Потому что активрекордовый `join` никак не меняет исходный `SELECT syslogs.*`. Можно сделать `join` и добавить в `select` нужное, но зачем, когда есть прелоад? Особого прироста производительности уже не будет. Есть ещё `eager_load`, он всегда использует `LEFT OUTER JOIN` и делает нужные селекты, а `includes` сам решает, что в данном случае лучше, и по необходимости тоже может джойнить (в случае, если в запросе есть where по связанной таблице, например). https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes - тут подробнее